# Set HTTP code onException with Camel and Restlet

Tags: exception, apache-camel, restlet, http-status-codes

Using the [Restlet component](https://camel.apache.org/restlet.html) in an Apache Camel project, I am not able to set the  HTTP status code on the response in [`onException`](https://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html).

Consider a Camel `RouteBuilder` configured like this:

```
onException(Exception.class)
  .handled(true)
  .process(new FailureResponseProcessor());

from("restlet:http://example.com/foo")
  .process(fooProcessor)
  .to("file:data/outbox");
```

In the `FailureResponseProcessor` I try to set the HTTP response code for Restlet:

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
  Response response = exchange.getIn()
                              .getHeader(RestletConstants.RESTLET_RESPONSE,
                                         Response.class);
    response.setStatus(Status.SERVER_ERROR_INTERNAL);
}
```

This does not work. The status of the the HTTP response is always `200 OK`.

What is necessary to effecively set the HTTP status code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are just retrieving the response object and changing it. This does not propagate down the route. You need to set the header after modifying the object.

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader(RestletConstants.RESTLET_RESPONSE, response);
```

Thanks.

Comment: This helped me into the right direction. The actual problem was that in a Processor upstream the headers where not propagated.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the status code for your exception by setting

```
.onException(MyException.class).process(SetFailureResponse::new).handled(true)
```

and in a separated SetFailureResponse class set

```
@Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.getMessage().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE,400);
    }
```